# How can i use my optical bay for more connecting port?

Tags: sata, expansion

I saw online, people use for more storage their optical bay. they remove it and replace with ssd or Hdd.

I searched online but noting found. Is there any way to using my SATA port to multiple usb or other ports?

Comment: Nope. They're completely different sorts of ports electrically and logically. There's no way this would work.

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: There is, however, hardware that connects to the relevant internal ports (USB, SATA, audio, ...) and offer a set of such ports externally accessible. Maybe that's what you are looking for? Note that hardware recommendation questions are off topic on Super User, as they tend to become outdated quickly.

Comment: İ looking for a optical bay thing has usb ports...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're pertaining to 5.25" bays, you can purchase adapters online that turns them into many things, such as USB extension ports, and 3.5" HDD bay converters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think OP is talking about laptop optical bays

Comment: @redbeam_ Could be. Question itself is vaguely written, so I'm going into this with an assumption only.